# order files by modification time using filemtime()

Tags: php

I have a script which gives me the url of the various files. I have to order them with their last modification time using [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) .
SCRIPT:

```
 <?php  
            
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {  
            $string = $row["imagens"];
            $array=explode(",",$string);
            
            
            foreach ($array as $var) {
                
                
                
            ?>  
                <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item crop">
                    <a href="uploads/<?php echo $var;?>" data-lightbox="proejtos">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/<?php echo $var;?>" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
              <?php  
            }};  
            ?>
```

Comment: That's nice. So what's your question?

Comment: Where is your mysql query ?

Comment: the question is:
how can i list my images by uploaded date

Comment: do you have the `uploaded date` inside the array `$array` ?

Comment: No, that is my code, i've tryed sort but with no success

Comment: order by date_column desc in your mysql query

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: All my images name are in a single ID in my database

Comment: Where you have the image upload dates? The date is inside the image name or inside the database?

Comment: no, i want to order by date uploaded, i've tryied with filemtime

Comment: filemtime gives the last modification time of the file. It is not used to get the last uploaded time of the file [You can check this in php manual](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php). Instead you can put the timestamp to the uploaded images or setup inside the database to have the original upload time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
  $sorting = array();

  //while whatever images you get
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)){
    $url = $row['url'];/*Put your images url*/


    //get the time of the file
    $timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i:s",filemtime($url));

    //add the time and url of the image
    $sorting[$timestamp] = $url;
  }


  //sort the array with respect to time
  ksort($sorting);

  foreach($sorting as $x => $x_value) {
      echo "Image uploaded on = " . $x . ", has url : " . $x_value;
      echo "<br>";
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Image uploaded on = 04-15-2016 07:17:54, has url : advertise/15042016184608-QPLVCzm0qi1460489950191-3.png
>  Image uploaded
>   on = 04-15-2016 18:24:19, has url :
>   advertise/15042016184608-QPLVCzm0qi1460489950191-1.png
>  Image uploaded
>   on = 04-17-2016 18:28:38, has url :
>   advertise/17042016182838-QPLVCzm0qi1460489950191-5.png

**Setting up for descending order:**
The function [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) arranges the stamps in the Increasing order where as to arrange the stamps in decreasing order (To put new images/file on top) the function [krsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) is used. The ksort/krsort function arranges the array with the decreasing or increasing order of the key. To arrange the array with respect to the values instead of key the function [asort()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_asort.asp) is used.

Answer (score 0):

You must have creted_at (for example) field in your table. Set the value of this field to actual time. Then when you want to order your items by a date (time) you can simply get this value by your query and order it. BTW: I recomment you to use some of PHP frameworks like Laravel, they make this really easier, you don`t have to care about these things, it will do it for you.

Comment: Ok, but if i just want to list by last modification the images with this code of mine, there is any possibilities?